# How to order data based on repeated dates in R

Tags: r, sorting

Suppose that the following dataset is available:

```
       date           V1     V2
[1,] 1996-01-01   1.4628995  12
[2,] 1996-01-01   0.1972603  11
..............
[3,] 1996-02-01   0.1205479  11
[4,] 1996-02-01   0.9643836   9
..............
[5,] 1996-03-01   0.1972603  14
[6,] 1996-03-01   0.1205479   8
```

How can i order `V1` in ascending order, for example, for each specific date, with the remaining variables, `V2,V3...` and so on, to follow the ordering. Like this:

```
           date           V1     V2
    [1,] 1996-01-01   0.1972603  11
    [2,] 1996-01-01   1.4628995  12
    ..............
    [3,] 1996-02-01   0.1205479  11
    [4,] 1996-02-01   0.9643836   9
    ..............
    [5,] 1996-03-01   0.1205479   8
    [6,] 1996-03-01   0.1972603  14
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just use `order` ie `data[order(data$V1),]`

Comment: this just orders based on `V1`, which changes the ordering of the dates. Which isn't desirable. The dates need to remain intact in their ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort by date and then by V1...

```
data <- data[order(as.Date(data$date),data$V1),]
```

In response to follow-up question in comment below, the rows with the two smallest values of V1 for each date can easily be selected using `dplyr`...

```
library(dplyr)
data2 <- data %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(rank(V1,ties.method = "min")<3)
```

Or, rather less intuitively, using base-R...

```
data2 <- data[as.logical(ave(data$V1,data$date,FUN=function(v) rank(v,ties.method = "min")<3)),]
```

You might need to fiddle with the parameters of `rank` to adjust the treatment of `NA` and the way it handles ties.  See `?rank`

Comment: Thank you! this was perfect!

Comment: I was wondering, is it possible to select the first two smallest values of `V1` for each date? (suppose that each date is repeated 100 times with each having a different `V1` value).

Comment: I've added something on this to the answer above.

Comment: I see! so basically, with this function `%>%` and `filter` of the `dplyr` package, i could also make a further filtering i.e. selecting the observations for each groupdate that are closest to `-0.5` AND `0.5` : `data2 %>% group_by(date) %>% which( (V3-0.5) == min(V3-0.5))` ?

Comment: Yes - for that you would need something like `%>% filter(V1==V1[which.min(abs(V1-0.5))] | V1==V1[which.min(abs(V1+0.5))])`

Comment: If you're new to `dplyr`, the RStudio cheat sheet gives a good introduction... https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf.  It is well worth learning, as it simplifies quite a lot of data manipulation tasks.

Comment: Thank you! one last thing if i may! in the `rank` function, there is no option to select all ties. Because i have more than one tie in each rank. After trying all options, i saw for many date groups to be having only the first rank and not the second one too.

Comment: `ties.method = "min"` is probably the one you want - so if there are several in joint second place, all will be given rank 2, and thus be included in the `rank<3` test

Comment: that is what i was thinking to! but sadly, i.e. for my first date, it only gives the 1st smaller number! which is weird.

Comment: It probably means the smallest value appears twice, so each will get rank 1, and the next value will have rank 3.  If you want the two smallest values, however many times they occur, then try `data2 <- data %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(V1 %in% sort(unique(V1))[1:2])`

Comment: Thank you so much! that worked. I wish i could +1 you even more.

Comment: No problem. It's the thought that counts!

Comment: Sorry for bringing this back, but i noticed something weird after exploring the results, for a few dates (20 out of 226), the `data %>% group_by(date) %>% filter(V1 %in% sort(unique(V1))[1:2])` returned only the 1st highest value. For the remaining 206 it returned both 1st and 2nd. Can you imagine what could be the issue?

Could it be: because of the sorting `[1:2]`; for those days, the second highest being a larger value than the values included in `sort()[1:2]`?

Comment: As long as there are at least two different values of V1, then `sort(unique(V1))[1:2]` will give the smallest two values.  Where it might fail is if there is only one unique value of V1 for a particular date.  Or perhaps if there are two very close values (e.g. the result for 1,1.0000000001,2 might look like 1,1).  If the latter, perhaps round V1 before this stage e.g. `data$V1 <- round(data$V1,digits=6)`

Comment: for example: there is this date with the min value being 0.04 and the next highest `v1` value being 0.139, which is quite a difference between them. However, it only returns the 0.04! That's why it is weird. It worked perfectly on the other dates!!

Comment: Strange. Try extracting the df for just that date and then run `sort(unique(data$V1))` on it to see what happens.

Comment: After looking one by one the dates, there was for one variable a missing value, which variable i use to do a filtering. Running complete cases at the very beginning fixed this issue!